# Capturing Log string in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, logging

So I have this log string where I need to capture the time, class, status, and log message.

```
Jun 18, 2014 5:50:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 18, 2014 5:55:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 18, 2014 5:55:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

This should be relatively easy, and I have been using regular expressions for just a short while but I know a good gist of them. However, can anyone help me out?

I've gotten this far, but for some reason, I can not group the two lines all into one grouping.  http://regex101.com/r/kI9pX7

UPDATE: http://regex101.com/r/sN9qC8
However, I don't want to group the colons, but just display the log message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the grouping for individual segment. Use previous segment to match next one.

For e.g to find out the class name I used time regex pattern and to find the log message I used log level pattern.

1. Date:

   ```
   ([A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d{1,})
   ```
2. Time:

   ```
   (\d{4}\s\d{1,}:\d{1,}:\d{1,}\s[AP]M)
   ```
3. Class Name:

   ```
   \d{4}\s\d{1,}:\d{1,}:\d{1,}\s[AP]M\s([^\s].*?)\s
   ```
4. Log Level:

   ```
   (^[^:][A-Z]+:)
   ```
5. Log Message:

   ```
   ^[^:][A-Z]+:\s(.*)$
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but how would you be able to group the whole thing?

Comment: Simply append all separated by pipe `|` symbol and get all group by index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to match across lines like that.  Instead, first collapse the log entries on to one line (do a search for \n characters preceding INFO and replace it with an empty string), then do the regex you've got.  I think that will work.